# PHP running a session through a proxy?

Tags: php, session, proxy

Basically, what I have is an account checker that needs to be ran through the use of proxies. The way I need it to work is, the user can place a proxy list into the site and the PHP script will connect through a proxy, gradually going down the list as 1 proxy for ever 2 accounts.

- Account list format: `email:password`
- Proxy list format: `IP:Port`

Is this possible?

If so, where do I start to look as I have no clue at the moment, I thought maybe someone on here could help?

Regards,

Comment: It's not clear. Is the user using a proxy to connect to your server, or is your application using a proxy to connect to a different server? And what part does the session play in this? Could you show some code?

Comment: The user just provides the proxy list, for the script to run a session with the proxy

Comment: What do you mean "run a session with the proxy"? Are you talking about PHP sessions as in `session_start()` and `$_SESSION`, or something else?

Comment: The script is checking a website automatically to input the email and password. I need it to connect to the website using a proxy.

Comment: See all the `CURLOPT_PROXYxxx` options in `curl_setopt`.